# How to check items in a list in pairs

Tags: python, list, turtle-graphics

I'm working on python with Turtle random path generator. I have the turtle work on a plane starting from origin and moving by units of `10px` North, South, East, or, West until it hits a set border. I don't want it to go on the same coordinate twice so I run it I add the past coordinates in a list and it grows like this: `[0, 0]` then `[0, 0, 10, 0]` then `[0, 0, 10, 0, 10, -10]` etc. My question is how I could compare the items in the list in pairs like `(0, 0) (10, 0) (10, -10)` etc because my current method of keeping the `x` and `y` in two separate lists prevents it from going on entire axis's. Here is my [code](https://repl.it/J7vJ/4).

Comment: Try working with a list of (x,y) tuples

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

```
next_coordinate = [10, 10]

if next_coordinate not in [[visited[2*i], visited[2*i+1]] for i in range(len(visited) / 2)]:
    # make step...
```

However, I think that you can store visited points in better way. For example, list of tuples:

```
[(0, 0), (10, 0), (10, -10)]
```

Or with two-dimensional matrix.

A matrix uses `O(n*n)` memory. It has fast lookups, but requires more memory.

Lists use memory in proportion to the number of visited coordinates pairs, which might save a lot of memory if you need to store huge amount of points.

Answer (score 0):

You may need creat a class position and put the positions into a list

```
class Position(object):
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x= x
        self.y= y

my_moves = []

for i in range(100):
    my_moves.append(Position(i*10,y*10))

# to get your moves

for obj in my_moves:
    print obj.x + "," obj.y
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch from a list of `xys` coordinates to a list of tuples, you can use `zip` and a list comprehension:

```
>>> xys = [0, 0, 10, 0, 10, -10]
>>> [xy for xy in zip(xys[::2], xys[1::2])]
[(0, 0), (10, 0), (10, -10)]
```

If you want a fast way to check if a point was already visited, you can keep a set of tuples:

```
>>> already_visited = set(xy for xy in zip(xys[::2], xys[1::2]))
>>> (10,0) in already_visited
True
>>> (10,10) in already_visited
False
```